# How can i solve search landing page attributes not working

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, search, landing-pages, search-type

When I try to search some keywords in sites, its return no results, I try to click search landing page left side attributes, its show products count but there are no products for results,

[image]

How can I solve this,

Comment: can you share your site url ?

Comment: Make sure your product should have visiblity catalog/search in product configuration

Comment: In my site all products have visibility, (catalog,search) still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all your product status enabled.